# How to add data to message body of post with HttpClient 4.3

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient, apache-httpcomponents

I've been using HttpClient 4.1 and I decided to upgrade to 4.3, but my code to set the message body of a post is now using deprecated functionality. It seems like the HttpClient API changes with almost every minor release, so I'm having trouble finding out what the code changes should be among a sea of existing HttpClient questions and topics relating to different versions.

My existing code is like this:

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
request.setEntity(new StringEntity(data, mimetype, HTTP.UTF_8)); // deprecated
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javadoc is your friend in most of these cases. It is clearly specified in [StringEntity java doc](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/StringEntity.html#StringEntity(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

```
Deprecated. (4.1.3) use StringEntity(String, ContentType)
```